# core plot scatter plot x y axis label not being displayed correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, scatter-plot

I tried to plot an activity using name of months against some data on the y axis. I wanted the y to show data such as 20, 40, 50, 60, ...120 while the x was supposed to be only Jan, Feb, Mar. This is what I want

[Click This link here](https://twitter.com/jsoniz/status/350826755277344768/photo/1)

and this is what I am getting

[Click This link here](https://twitter.com/jsoniz/status/350826833551454208/photo/1)
Someone know how to fix this, please?

xValues and yValues are just `NSMutables` with data of 
xValues [0, 5, 15, 20...50...60...70..]
yValues [60, 70, 80, 50, 40....]

the codes are below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  @interface GraphManager_ : NSObject<CPTPlotDataSource>
  @property (strong, nonatomic)CPTGraphHostingView *hostView;
  @property (strong, nonatomic)UIView *plotContainerView;
  @property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *xValue;
  @property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *yValue;
  @property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *plotTitle;


-(id) initScatterPlot:(UIView *)plotContainerView plotTitle:(NSString *)plotTitle xValue:(NSMutableArray *)xValues yValues:(NSMutableArray *) yValues;

-(void)configureGraph;
-(void)configureXAxis;
-(void)configureYAxis;
-(void)configurePlot;
-(void)drawScatterPlot;

@end


#import "GraphManager_.h"

@implementation GraphManager_

 @synthesize plotContainerView = _plotContainerView;
 @synthesize plotTitle = _plotTitle;
 @synthesize hostView = _hostView;
 @synthesize xValue = _xValues;
 @synthesize yValue = _yValues;


-(id)initScatterPlot:(UIView *)plotContainerView plotTitle:(NSString *)plotTitle xValue:  (NSMutableArray *)xValues yValues:(NSMutableArray *)yValues{

    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.plotContainerView = plotContainerView;
        self.plotTitle = plotTitle;
        self.xValue = xValues;
        self.yValue = yValues;
     }
    return self;

  }



 -(void)configureGraph{


    CGRect plotContainerViewBound = _plotContainerView.bounds;
plotContainerViewBound = CGRectMake(_plotContainerView.frame.origin.x, _plotContainerView.frame.origin.y, 1025, 560);

    _hostView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:plotContainerViewBound];
    _hostView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [_plotContainerView addSubview:_hostView];

    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:_hostView.bounds];
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainBlackTheme]];
    _hostView.hostedGraph = graph;

    //tweaking the graph
    graph.paddingTop    = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingBottom = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingLeft   = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingRight  = 30.0f;

    graph.titleTextStyle = [self textStyle];
    graph.title = _plotTitle;

    graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 4.0f);

    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    = 20.0f;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 40.0f;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   = 40.0f;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  = 40.0f;

    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderColor = nil;

    graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.fill = [[CPTFill alloc] initWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:23.0f/255.0f green:38.0f/255.0f blue:57.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];

}

-(void)configureYAxis{

     NSNumberFormatter *yAxisLabelFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     [yAxisLabelFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];

    //configuring the x and y axis
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)_hostView.hostedGraph.graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0f];
    y.majorIntervalLength = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:20] decimalValue];
    y.labelFormatter = yAxisLabelFormatter;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = [self xyGridLineStyle];
    y.axisLineStyle = [self xyGridLineStyle];
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
    y.majorTickLength = 0.0f;
    y.minorTickLength = 0.0f;
 }

-(void)configureXAxis{
   CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)_hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
   CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
   x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0f];
   x.majorIntervalLength = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] decimalValue];//to be taken outside
   //x.labelFormatter = yAxisLabelFormatter;
   x.majorGridLineStyle = [self xyGridLineStyle];
   x.axisLineStyle = [self xyGridLineStyle];
   x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
   x.majorTickLength = 0.0f;
   x.minorTickLength = 0.0f;
   x.majorTickLocations = [self majorXTickLocations];
   x.axisLabels = [self smallMonthLabels];
   x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
}

-(void)configurePlot{

  CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  plot.dataSource = self;

  CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)_hostView.hostedGraph.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
  [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:plot,nil]];
  plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(120.0)];
  plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(50.0)];

  CPTMutableLineStyle *plotLineStyle = [plot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
  plotLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:63.0f/255.0f green:241.0f/255.0f blue:124.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
  plotLineStyle.lineWidth = 5.0f;
  plot.dataLineStyle = plotLineStyle;

  CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
  plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:51.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:51.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
  plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);
  plotSymbol.lineStyle = plotLineStyle;
  plot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
  [_hostView.hostedGraph.graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:_hostView.hostedGraph.graph.defaultPlotSpace];

}

-(void)drawScatterPlot{


  [self configureGraph];

  [self configureYAxis];

  [self configureXAxis];

  [self configurePlot];
}

-(NSSet *)customAxisLabels:(NSArray *)customLabelSet{

  CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
  textStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
  textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
  textStyle.fontSize = 18.0f;

  NSMutableArray *customTickLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_xValues.count];

  for(int i=0; i < _xValues.count; i++){
     [customTickLocations addObject:[_xValues objectAtIndex:i]];
  }

  NSMutableSet *customLabel = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:customTickLocations.count];


  for(int i = 0; i<[customTickLocations count] -1; i++){
      NSNumber *tickLocation = [customTickLocations objectAtIndex:i];

      CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [customLabelSet objectAtIndex:i]] textStyle:textStyle];
      newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
      [customLabel addObject:newLabel];
  }

  return customLabel;
}

-(CPTMutableTextStyle *)textStyle{
   //text styles
   CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
   textStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
   textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
   textStyle.fontSize = 18.0f;

   return textStyle;
}

-(CPTMutableLineStyle *)xyGridLineStyle{

//xy grid line style
  CPTMutableLineStyle *xyGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
  xyGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:25.0f/255.0f green:60.0f/255.0f blue:94.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
  xyGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.50f;
  return xyGridLineStyle;
}

-(NSSet *) majorXTickLocations{
    return [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:_xValues];
}

-(NSSet *)majorYTickLocations{
    return [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:_yValues];
}

-(NSSet *)smallMonthLabels{
    NSArray *shortenedMonthNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Jan", @"Feb", @"Mar", @"Apr", @"May", @"Jun", @"Jul", @"Aug", @"Sep",@"Oct", @"Nov", @"Dec", nil];

    return [self customAxisLabels:shortenedMonthNames];

}

-(NSSet *)amPmTimeLabels{
        NSArray *ampmSet = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12am",@"1", @"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11", @"Noon",@"1",@"2", @"3", @"4", @"5",@"6", @"7", @"8", @"9",@"10", @"11pm", nil];
        return [self customAxisLabels:ampmSet];
}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot{
      return [self.xValue count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx{
      if(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX){
         return [self.xValue objectAtIndex:idx];
      }else{
         return [self.yValue objectAtIndex:idx];
   }

}
@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GraphManager_.h"
#import "GraphDataManager.h"

@interface testVC_ : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *dailyRateGraphView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GraphManager_ *graphManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GraphDataManager *graphDataManager;

@end


#import "testVC_.h"

@interface testVC_ ()

@end

@implementation testVC_



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     self.graphDataManager = [GraphDataManager sharedInstance];
     [self.graphDataManager getDailyHeartRateData];

      self.graphManager = [[GraphManager_ alloc] initScatterPlot:self.dailyRateGraphView
                                                plotTitle:@"Sample Data"
                                                          xValue:self.graphDataManager.xAxisLabelValues
                                                  yValues:self.graphDataManager.yAxisLabelValues];
      [self.graphManager drawScatterPlot];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
       [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

@end
```

Comment: I assume you're calling `-drawScatterPlot` to set everything up, right? Is the datasource getting called?

Comment: Yes @EricSkroch. I am calling -drawScatterPlot to draw the plot. It must be because as you can see in the image link i posted I get the first value "Jan" on the x axis

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems in the code you posted. However, the plot space ranges aren't changing from the default [0, 1]. Focus your troubleshooting around that fact. One suggestion: since you're using the default plot space anyway, try `[_hostView.hostedGraph.graph addPlot:plot];`. It should be equivalent to your code, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @EricSkroch i tried your suggestion. Still the same problem. There is one other thing

Comment: @EricSkroch i tried your suggestion. Still the same problem no change. There is one other thing. when i change CPTXYAxisSet *xaxisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)_hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet to "...._hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet the x axis displays only numbers from 0 to 1.0. This is driving me nuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change any references to `_hostView.hostedGraph.graph` to `_hostView.hostedGraph`. The `graph` property is inherited from `CPTLayer`. It is used by other parts of the graph to maintain a pointer to the graph, but not by the graph itself.

Comment: Thanks!!. you saved my weekend. That worked for correcting the x and y axis but now the values are inverted [Look here](https://twitter.com/jsoniz/status/351368186832252928/photo/1) what happened. The x and y axis are inverted down side up

Comment: The iOS hosting view inverts its hosted layer (the graph) so we can use the same drawing code on Mac and iOS. Check your view hierarchy and make sure you don't (for example) have one hosting view inside another.